# Import node standard modules into TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I think this is an incredibly simple question, but for some reason I cannot find a definite answer online:
What is the correct way of importing standard NodeJS libraries in TypeScript?

I have installed `@types/node`, but when trying to import from it, I only get errors.
For example, I am trying to import `net`. In JS:

```js
const net = require('net');
```

In TS I have tried:

```js
import * as net from 'net';  // Cannot find module 'net' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
import * as net from 'node/net';  // File '[...]@types/node/net.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
import * as net from 'node:net';  // Cannot find module 'node:net' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "strict": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "typeRoots": [
            "../node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

I bet this is a total rookie mistake, but I am at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your tsconfig.json file, your node_modules folder is in the same directory as you tsconfig.json file, so `typeRoots` key should be
 `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]`
or you could just delete it because it's considered visible (from typescript documentation):

By default all visible ”@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible.

Also fix the path also in the exclude key

Comment: Thank you! I should've been more careful when setting up the `tsconfig.json`. Typical "follow a guide and pay too little attention" problem...